# AIDE doesn't recognise colorPrimary

Tags: android, aide-ide

Using AIDE on phone to create apps...
Dont know why but AIDE doesn't recognise the colorPrimary & colorPrimaryDark...
throws error like 'No Resource Found'

I am currently able to change the ActionBar color by this Code -

`

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#075E54</item>
</style>
```

`

How do I change the StatusBar color?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` and  `colorAccent` to `MyActionBarTheme`

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/DarkBlue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#01517f</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/Gray2</item>
</style>
```

replace the values for colors to what you want.